# Help Request: Getting Batch Java Compiler Finished To Work

Tags: java, batch-file, request, compilation

Ok, So I have been making this All-in-One Batch File Compiler for Java Files, to compile the Class Files, Manifest files, and the Jar Files. Everything works but one thing... I can't seem to figure out how to call another path in certain cases.. I will explain a case example below the Batch Code:

```
@ echo off
COLOR 0a
Title Leaum's All-In-One Java Compiler

echo Compiling The Class Files...
"Whattt to do here?!" C:\JavaApps
javac -classpath . *.java
Pause
cls

echo Type the CLASS File Name Exactly...
set Man=
set /p Man=Type CLASS File Name: %=%
pause
echo Compiling The Manfiest File...
echo Main-Class: %Man%>>manifest.txt
pause
cls
```

I posted it in pastebin because the code thing was being weird.
Anyway, Line 6 for example, let's say I want it to call that Folder to Search for certain .Java Files when it needs to. When ever I am compiling a Java file that contains for example "TextIO.putln" Code, I would need it to call the TextIO.java/Class file in order for it to compile correctly, and I just want to store all the standalone/applet files in a separate directory... And have it include that in the Class Compiler, But still create the Class Files in what ever directory the Current project .Java is in.. If any of this makes sense? I can't seem to find a way to make it call the TextIO though :3.

Any help would be great. Thank you!

Comment: pastebin doesn't work for code here. It means it's not searchable, and it makes it difficult for people to see in relation to your question. Please edit your post and add the code properly. I'd offer help in "the code thing being weird", but you didn't define what that means, so I can't. All I can say is to paste your code into the editor starting on a new line, highlight it all, and either: click the button with the {} or press Ctrl+K. You can also just indent each line at least 4 spaces to format as code. Post your code here and someone will edit it to clean it up for you.

Comment: @Ken White I pasted the code, but it still did not put the whole thing in the code line. I hope it's somewhat understandable.

Comment: I would suggest reading the formatting help here http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson I prefer using CMD :3 Not really sure why... I guess I tend to be old fashion?

Comment: I know why ... not invented here syndrome, all my suggestions **are command line tools** specifically made for the purpose of managing the building of Java projects.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question right, you simply need to add the directory containing your utility classes to the classpath for the compiler, e.g.:

```
javac -classpath .;C:\JavaApps *.java
```

But I do agree with Jarrod and others that, in the long run, it is better to learn to use a build tool.

Comment: Essentially yes, However.. My project is in C:\Users\Leaum\Documents\Java\ and it is let's say Hello.java. And it requires the TextIO.Java/Class which is in C:\JavaApps... I want it to build everything in C:\Users\Leaum\Documents\Java\ and just pull the TextIO from JavaApps... I just can't figure that out D:

I will use a Builder at one point. But I am going to be teaching my spouse Java, and I think it would be best for her to start out the same way I did, Compiling in CMD, I am just trying to make a Batch to save some time and making it easier, ya know? Hope ya can help. Thanks

Comment: Also the Batch File is in the \Documents\Java directory, just to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't re-invent this wheel**, especially in a platform specific language!

Learn [Maven 3](http://maven.apache.org/) or at least [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or even [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/). [SCons](http://www.scons.org/) would even be preferable to Windows specific batch files, there is nothing of value to learn from the approach you are taking.

Comment: I don't really see an issue in using a Batch File to Compile Java Files? I mean it's basically doing the same thing in DoS..

Comment: @Leaum if you don't see what is wrong with your approach, it doesn't mean my answer is wrong, it means you don't have the experience to appreciate why it is correct.

Comment: This isn't an answer; it's a comment at best. "How do I cook an egg?" "Don't. They have restaurants and chefs for that." If you want to provide advice on better ways, do it as a comment or after you've answered the question asked. :)

Comment: @Ken White, that is your opinion, mine is if someone on my team had asked me this question, I would tell them the same thing, its a complete wast of time and money. You are doing it wrong, and some alternatives that are better practices. All the existing Java build tools exist because batch files didn't cut it in 1996, and they definitely don't have a place in good advice today, so I think addressing the batch file specifics is bad advice, and SO should be about **good advice** as much or more so about correct advice, which are **not** the same thing.